# Can not able to get exact value of `%u` in Vala program

Tags: vala

Vala newbie here. Learning Vala as programming language and stuck with following program

```
int main() {
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    uint age;

    stdout.printf("Enter your first name: ");
    first_name = stdin.read_line();

    stdout.printf("Enter your last name: ");
    last_name = stdin.read_line();

    stdout.printf("Enter your age: ");
    age = stdin.scanf("%u", out age);

    stdout.printf("Hi! %s %s. You are %u years old.\n", first_name, last_name, age);

    return 0;
}
```

This program is working fine except the value of `%u` or age. Whatever value that I entered, it always printing `1`.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the return value to `age`. The return value for `scanf` is documented as:

> On  success,  these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

Since you're attempting to read 1 value, if the input is read successfully the return value will be 1.

Try something like

`if (stdin.scanf("%u", out age) < 1)
  GLib.error("Unable to parse age");`

Comment: Got your point. But, is there way I can get the entered value of age and display it. For example, if I entered `24`, then it should display `24` as age?

Comment: With the line I posted `age` should contain `24`. Notice that you're still passing `age` as an out param to `scanf`, you're just not clobbering it with the return value afterwards.

Comment: aha! `age =` should not be there. Got it. Thanks.